# How select a element by name in puppeter?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://www.reddit.com/")

    await page.click("._3Wg53T10KuuPmyWOMWsY2F.Z_HUY3BUsGOBOtdmH94ZS.q_unSaY23rpdd3lDvGZ-._2iuoyPiKHN3kfOoeIQalDT._10BQ7pjWbeYP63SAPNS8Ts.HNozj_dKjQZ59ZsfEegz8._2Z-LWN_PrkTncEM_mPuEW5")

    await page.type('input[name="username"]', process.env.username);

    await page.type('input[name="password"]', process.env.password);

})();
```

I need knows if it's posible select a element by name and not with id or class, more than anything to take it into account in future pages.

Comment: In general, puppeteer should support attribute selectors quite fine, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/puppeteer/puppeteer_attribute_selector.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
await page.locator('input[name="username"]').fill(process.env.username_name)

await page.locator('input[name="password"]').fill(process.env.password_pass)
```

I found that.